# Using PHP to calculate totals from an array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

This isn't an appropriate forum as I'm not a programmer and make simple mistakes but I cannot find an answer to this sum. 
I have a table column called on0 which contains Option 1, Option 2, Option 3 or Option 4
each of these have a value of 2, 5, 10, or 20.
I am trying to select all the rows and change the value to a number and then use array_sum to total the column values.
I have written it several ways and below is an example but every way I try the total is either the last value in the array or zero. I would really appreciate any input as to what I am doing wrong:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connection.inc.php');
$conn = dbConnect('read', 'pdo');
$sql = 'SELECT on0 FROM members ORDER BY on0 ASC';
$result = array();
  foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    if ($row['on0']=="Option 1") {$result[] = 2;}
    elseif ($row['on0']=="Option 2") {$result[] = 5;}
    elseif ($row['on0']=="Option 3") {$result[] = 10;}
    elseif ($row['on0']=="Option 4") {$result[] = 20;}
  }
  $tote = array($result);
echo "Value: $" . array_sum($tote) . ".00" . "\n"; 
?>
```

this code produces $0.00 in PHP
if I remove the [] so it is {$result = 2;} etc. the result is the last value ie: $20.00
I have also tried placing the result in quote marks as {$result[] = '2';} and "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need an array
main problem is `+=` instead of `=`

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connection.inc.php');
$conn = dbConnect('read', 'pdo');
$sql = 'SELECT on0 FROM members ORDER BY on0 ASC';
$result = 0;
  foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    if ($row['on0']=="Option 1") {$result += 2;}
    elseif ($row['on0']=="Option 2") {$result += 5;}
    elseif ($row['on0']=="Option 3") {$result += 10;}
    elseif ($row['on0']=="Option 4") {$result += 20;}
  }
echo "Value: $" . $result . ".00" . "\n"; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution mask and to Barmar. I didn't realise I was overcomplicating what I was after - thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap `$result` in another array. It's already an array. So you can just do:

```
echo "Value: $" . array_sum($result) . ".00" . "\n";
```